# Failed to manipulate the string passed as pointer to pointer inside the function

Tags: c, pointer-to-pointer

I am creating a `removeNonAlphaCharacters` function trying to remove all non alphabetic characters using C.

I could remove all non-alphabetic characters inside the function, but I can not pass the modified string back the original string, which means I can't override the original string directly inside the function even using double pointer. Does anyone have an idea what's going wrong in my code?

The final `printf` inside the `main` function won't print me the **HelloData** for me, however the one inside the `removeNonAlphaCharacters` function could give me the correct output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int removeNonAlphaCharacters(char ** source);

int main() {
    char * source = "Hello 2 Data!";
    char **sourcePointer = &source;
    int result = 0;
    result = removeNonAlphaCharacters(sourcePointer);
    printf("we have successfully removed %i characters from the string.\n", result);
    printf("The modified result is: %s", source);
    return 0;
}

int removeNonAlphaCharacters(char ** source) {
    char *dest = *source;
    size_t sourceLength = strnlen(*source, 100);
    char *str = malloc(sourceLength*sizeof(char));
    int removeNum = 0;
    for (; *dest != '\0'; dest++) {
        if (*dest >= 'A' && *dest <= 'Z' || *dest >= 'a' && *dest <= 'z') {
            *str = *dest;
            str++;
        }
        else {
            removeNum++;
            continue;
        }
    }
    printf("The modified result is: %s\n", str-(sourceLength-removeNum));
    *source = malloc((sourceLength-removeNum) * sizeof(char));
    strncpy(*source, str, 100);
    return removeNum;
```

I tried to use `malloc` to allocate memory inside the function, and it didn't work for me. And I also tried directly override the original string inside the `removeNonAlphaCharacters` function without allocating memory, which will end up into the Memory Error `SIGBUS`.

Comment: Looks ok but you forgot to null terminate the `str` after the copy. Add a `*str = '\0'` after the `for` loop, does that solve the problem?

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is, by definition, 1, so there's no need to multiply in the `malloc()` parameter. But... If there are no characters removed, `*str` will not have sufficient space for the terminating `'\0'`... Try: `char *str = malloc( sourceLength + 1 );` AND, the attempt to copy the string won't work because, in a perfect world, `str` is pointing at the end of the string... (PS: Just noticed the 2nd `malloc()` is also too short...)

Comment: That is quite a round-a-bout way to remove non-alpha characters. You can simply pass the string as a single-pointer (it points to where the actual chars are stored in memory) and then update the string in place. Simply use a *read* pointer and *write* pointer (you can simply use a write pointer if you iterate by index or don't provide a convenience return of the original pointer.  The string must be mutable (not a string-literal). See [Remove Non-Alpha](https://paste.opensuse.org/2ed19a5689c9) for an example. (link good until Thu 27 Apr 2023 02:19:46 AM CDT)

Comment: Also, consider `#include <ctype.h>` and calling `isalpha()` instead of the long conditional -- which you should group with additional `(() || ())` for clarity. Using `isalpha((unsigned char)*dest)` is much easier than `if (('A' <= *dest && *dest <= 'Z') || ('a' <= *dest && *dest <= 'z'))` -- and much less prone to an accidental typo.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is within your function, `removeNonAlphaCharacters`.

You create a new string `str` (i.e. a pointer to a char) and as you manipulate this string, your pointer is incrementing (in the line `str++`) hence when you call the function `strncpy`, the string you are copying is a pointer to the end of the string you want (not a pointer to the start).

To fix, modify the line containing `strncpy` to be

```
strncpy(*source, str-(sourceLength-removeNum), 100);
```

Don't forget as well to consider adding the null termination `'\0'` to your new string.

Comment: Worth mentioning that `strncpy()` is particularly inefficient for large string since it sets all characters past the end of the string to the nul-character.  See [man 3 strncpy](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html)